# AWS java lambda - "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there any way to get the java heap dump of a java lambda? I get an out of memory on the second run of my lambda, but unfortunately I can't find any tools similar to jprofiler that can be used with aws lambda (I've tried codeGuru and x-ray but it didn't help much).

Any advices on how to "debug" memory allocation of a lambda running on aws?

** Edit - I know how to run locally and check the memory using JProfiler and other such tools, but I need a specific scenario that is very hard to reproduce locally so I want specific solutions for aws lambda environment. **

Comment: Is there any reason you can't debug the memory allocation locally? The memory used locally will be near about very similar to how much is used inside the Lambda function.

Comment: When running locally, use the `-Xmx` command-line argument to limit heap space to what you'd get from Lambda.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I can't run the exact scenario locally (this lambda is complex and needs access to other aws features) - so I'm looking for a solution to use in aws (locally I'm running jprofiler, but as I mentioned - it's not the eact same behavior).

Comment: [CodeGuru Profiler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeguru/latest/profiler-ug/what-is-codeguru-profiler.html) claims, among other things, to help you understand your application's heap utilization over time. It supports Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "trigger heap dump from inside JVM" brought me to [this page by Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture), which has this code:

```
public static void dumpHeap(String filePath, boolean live) throws IOException {
    MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
      server, "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic", HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
    mxBean.dumpHeap(filePath, live);
}
```

I haven't tried it, but have verified that the `HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean` exists in the Corretto 17 distribution, so it's likely to be available to a Lambda. You should, of course, write a test Lambda to verify.

I would execute this code as the first thing in the Lambda invocation handler, looking only for live objects, and upload the file to S3. This will tell you if there's anything that you are unexpectedly holding from the previous call. If there isn't, you simply need more memory.

The problem that you might run into is that Lambda only provides 512 MB of file storage space, and heap dumps can easily be larger than that. If this is the case for you, then you'll need to use an EFS volume to hold the file (and there's no need to upload to S3).

I recommend using the Lambda's request ID (available from the context) to uniquely name the files. This will make it easy to trace back from the execution logs.

And finally, *this is something for development only.* It's going to add a lot of time to the Lambda invocation.

Comment: Great idea, I'll try that and update

Answer (score -2):

Setup AWS CLI

`aws iam list-mfa-devices --user-name <ur_user>`

use the SerialNumber from list-mfa-devices to get-session-token

```
aws sts get-session-token --duration-seconds 3600 --serial-number
        <SerialNumber> --token-code <<Say from Google authenticator>>

AWS_ACCESS_KEY=AccessKeyId
AWS_SECRET_KEY=SecretAccessKey
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=SessionToken
```

Pass above as environment variable when you launch your handler method locally (Say from Junit) with same memory settings as suggested by Parsifal. Same as ur Lambda memory setting value
Additionally pass below Vm argument
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\ur_path
This will generate HeapDump file and you can use Eclipse MAT to analyze memory leak
This is what I normally follow. This will work in any complex setup.
Thanks

Comment: Not clear what MFA has to do with this.

Comment: Your developer role need to get temporary access to AWS resources using STS or else you need some static  AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY with out that how you will access AWS resources from your local code ?

Comment: Normally we go with temporary credentials for that you need MFA (If MFA is enabled  for your user)which is standard best practice followed by Most of the organizations

Comment: The problem with running locally is not that the OP cannot get credentials, or at least that was not indicated. It's that the local environment is not a good replica of the Lambda runtime environment.

Comment: OP states " lambda is complex and needs access to other aws features" I Just posted What I normally do to access other AWS services from my local. If he  run his handler code with same data set it is easy to replicate the issue locally hoping he is running with normal x86 arch and not using any OS specific library (Linux so files)